# How can I write a custom function like $any() (type cast function)?

Tags: angular

the [$any() function](https://angular.io/guide/template-expression-operators#any-type-cast-function) can be used into template, eg.:

```
<p>The item's undeclared best by date is: {{$any(item).bestByDate}}</p>
```

I want implement my custom function `$myAny()`, eg.:

```
<p>The item's undeclared best by date is: {{$myAny(item).bestByDate}}</p>
```

How expose a function "globally" into every components template?

Comment: You cannot create a global template function. You can however, create a service and inject the service into the component. You can then use the service with the function: `myService.$myAny(item).bestByDate`.

Comment: You could create a pipe though. `item|$myAny:'bestByDate'`.